# mysql select all columns related to specific record

Tags: mysql, select

Let's say I have following tables:

#### Food

```
ID | title
---+----------
1  | sandwich
2  | spaghetti
```

#### Ingridients

```
ID  | food_reference | type | location | bought
----+----------------+------+----------+----------
100 | 1              | ham  | storeA   | 11-1-2013
101 | 1              | jam  | storeB   | 11-1-2013
102 | 2              | tuna | storeB   | 11-6-2013
```

And I want a select query which will find all matching rows, desired output:

```
{id:1,title:sandwich,ingridients:[
    {id:100,type:ham,location:storeA,bought:11-1-2013},
    {id:101,type:jam,location:storeB,bought:11-1-2013}],
id:2,title:spaghetti,ingridients:[
    {id:102,type:tuna,location:storeB,bought:11-6-2013}]}
```

So far I have something like this:

```
SELECT F.id, F.title, group_concat(I.d_id ,I.type,I.location,I.bought SEPARATOR ',') as ingridients,
FROM food F, ingridients I
WHERE F.id=I.food_reference
GROUP BY F.id
```

;

Problem is, that all those values are concatenated (obviously) resulting in this output:

```
{id:1,title:sandwich,ingridients:100hamstoreA11-1-2013,101jamstoreB11-1-2013},
{id:2,title:spaghetti,ingridients:102tunastoreB11-6-2013}
```

note: this output is created using function json_encode on object

So do you have any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

why can not you use inner join, just try

```
 select * from food inner join Ingredients on food.id=Ingridients.food_reference;
```

then try

```
SELECT foo.id, foo.title, 
group_concat(ing.d_id ,ing.type,ing.location,ing.bought   SEPARATOR ',') 
as ingredients,FROM food foo, ingridients ing   
WHERE foo.id=ing.food_reference;
```

Comment: well, the problem is that this way I get only one ingridient related to food (not all of them). I think it is because of the 'group by' statement

Comment: now check, I edited.. I think you can use both of this and you can make table using your programing language

Comment: yes, the group_concat is doing exactly what I want, BUT it creates just one string from all those columns listed as parameters

Comment: ok. good. if my answer helped you, accept it. all the best. thanks